# Is there a way to route to a specific div using express and hbs?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to route to a specific div on a page using express and hbs. I've tried tacking the id onto the end of the route but that didn't work. Below is the code that I've tried.

```
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => { res.render('contact#myDiv') })
```

Basically the goal is to render the hbs file and it goes down to the specific id, similar to what happens when you go to the url 'example.com/#myDiv'. Is there a way that I can do something like that?

Comment: Doesn't it already do that? If you have `/contact#myDiv` in your URL and render the `contact` handblebars template (and it has that element on it), then the browsers should scroll towards that element.

Comment: Not in my case. What I'm trying to do is press a button that submits a form, and if the user didn't fill in all the fields, it re renders the page with the fields they already put in. But when I re render the page, it goes to the top of the page. I want it to render at the div for the form which is #contactMe

Comment: Then you should redirect instead of reloading the template. `res.redirect('/contact#myDiv')`

Comment: I'm getting an invalid status code error

Comment: And if you manually add a status code? `res.redirect(302, '/contact#myDiv')`? I'm reading a lot of posts saying that hashes are a client-side domain system. So if the suggestion above won't work I'd suggest that you handle the error on the frontend, which will work for sure.

Comment: I figured out the problem, when I'm putting in the redirect, I'm passing expressions to handlebars as well, and res.redirect() doesn't support handlebars expressions. How would I pass the expressions to the template when redirecting?